# Display dynamic Controls at run time

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls

I want to display in a panel at run time different controls, depending on the menu selection.

Any ideas?

Comment: Question far too ambiguous and open-ended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Add all user controls inside a parent page with Visible = false. Depending menu selection, make Visible = true.

Advantages - Easy to implement

Disadvantages - Expensive. Every user control's Load event will be called on parent page is loaded.

2) Load a control dynamically to a place holder.

this.PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(child);

Advantages - Light weight.

Disadvantages - Need to write some code if parent page wants to retrieve data from user control after post back.

Answer (score 1):

Put all of the possible controls in your panel, and then (assuming you're using the ASP.Net Menu control) set the appropriate control's `.Visible` property to `True` and all the other control's `.Visible` properties to `False` in the `MenuItemClick` event.

Answer (score 1):

You only have to instantiate the controls you want and add it via

```
YourPanel.Controls.Add(yourcontrol)
```

I think that in VB must be almost the same.

Comment: Thanx.
I found this totorial:
http://quickstart.developerfusion.co.uk/QuickStart/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/userctrl/default.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you want all of your controls available always (for data sharing), you'll want to do as Joel suggested. Syntactically, however, I would say you could make it much easier if you associated the menu items to your controls inside the `Page_OnLoad()` like so:

```
Control1.Visible = MenuItem1.Selected;
Control2.Visible = MenuItem1.Selected || MenuItem2.Selected;
Control3.Visible = MenuItem3.Selected;
```

Hope that helps.